# Update one column based on the compare values between two different columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have telephone number code like this:

Table1

```
rownum TelephoneCode --TelephoneCode is integer datatype
-------------------        
  1       444
  2       555
  3       666
  4       777
```

I have another table having 3 columns(and country column is blank)

table2

```
  rownum country telephonenumber -- telephonenumber is varchar datatype
  -------------------------------
    1                 6661234(C)
    2                 4440987
    3                 9999870
    4                 555-1245
```

What I want is, my query should read the "TelephoneCode" from "Table1" and search that code in "tepephonenumber" column in "table2".
  If the "TelephoneCode" is found in "Table2" then update the "Country" column of "Table2" to "AU".

Hence my final table (i.e. table2) result should come like this:

Table2

```
  rownum country telephonenumber
  -------------------------------
    1        AU         6661234
    2        AU         4440987
    3                   9999870
    4        AU         5551245
```

Here is what I have tried. This query is executing successfully; however, not updating the "Country" Column of "Table2"

```
 declare @code int
 declare @parsedcode int
 declare @numcount int
 declare @numcount1 int
 declare @telephonenumberread varchar(max)



 while(@numcount <= 356)
 begin


   select @code= [TelephoneCode] from table1 where rownum = @numcount
 --select @code

 while(@numcount1 <=137992)
   begin
     select @telephonenumberread = TELPHONH from table2 where rownum = 
     @numcount1
   --print @telephonenumberread
   set @parsedcode = substring(@telephonenumberread,1,3)

   if(@code = @parsedcode)
     begin

         update table2 set country = 'AU'
         --return
     end
  --else

     set @numcount1 = @numcount1+1

 end

   set @numcount = @numcount+1
end
```

Hope I have explained it correctly.
Note:My table has more than 100K blank in the country column.

How to achieve this? Even, Im unable to print the values for the debug? What am I doing wrong?
  Thanks.

Comment: Your attempt seems overly complicated when it looks like you just want something like `update t2 set country = 'AU' from table2 as t2 join table1 as t1 on t2.telephonenumber like t1.telephonecode + '%'`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Oh, and as for what you're doing wrong in your procedure, you never initialise the values for your variables, so they're NULL by default and thus you'll never enter the while loop because NULL is not less than or equal to a number, it is NULL and thus cannot be compared with a number. Even if it did work, your update statement will update your ENTIRE table and not just the row you wanted to update. Also, you may be interested in reading [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches), or any other article about set-based thinking in SQL.

Comment: @ZKL The telephonecode and Telephonenumber does not have same datatype. Just updated my question. Additionally, sometimes the telephone code can be after 4 chars (like 1886  then 3 digit telephonecode then the 4 digit number i.e. 18866661234)

Comment: OK. If it's not the same data type, converting it to the same data type is not difficult. If telephone codes can have varying length, then you can just build in the necessary rules to the join. In any case, you should be doing your update with a join and adjust the logic of the join as necessary.

Comment: Yes. I have initialize the values to 0 and its going inside the loop. However, I'm getting this error now: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1-7' to data type int.

Comment: Don't use a loop... Use set-based logic. Unless you specify the rules of your join, it's hard to be more specific, but you should be aiming to do something like my first comment, with type conversion and any other rules you need. e.g. `UPDATE T2 SET Country = 'AU' FROM Table2 AS T2 JOIN TABLE1 AS T1 ON T2.TelephoneNumber LIKE (CAST T1.TelephoneCode AS VARCHAR(20)) + '%'` If there are specific rules for the join other than a pattern match, you build that into the join...

Comment: As ZLK said, an `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause or an `INNER JOIN` would update all records. Also ,you should always approach your SQL problem with statements that process groups of records at a time, which means avoiding things that update record by record. There are exceptions but they are very rare. Lastly, you said telephone codes could come up in the middle of telephone numbers, can there be cases where something in the middle of a number looks like a code but it is not a code? If there is, how to tell the difference?

Comment: @ZLK's answer works easily